# Linear independence of set in modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, free-modules

> Suppose $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and $N$ is a free $R$-module. **m** is a maximal ideal of $R$ and $m\in$ **m**. Then the set of elements $\{ x_1,x_2,...,x_{n-1}, m x_n \}$ which spans $N$ is not linearly independent.

My definition of free module is module with basis.

In case of integral domain, I proved it.

$$x_n=\alpha_1 x_1+...+\alpha_nmx_n$$
$$mx_n=m\alpha_1 x_1+...+m\alpha_nmx_n$$
Subtracting $mx_n$ gives,
$m(\alpha_nm-1)=0$. If $R$ is integral domain it forces either $m$ is unit or $0$. unit is not possible . So $m$ has to be 0. Showing that the last vector is redundant

But in general case i couldn't do. Please give a hint

Comment: This question arise while trying to prove rank of module is unique. I.e. number of basis elements is same for any basis

Comment: Is $N$ finite free?

Comment: Basically I was try to prove that if $x_i$ are basis of N . And m is maximal idea of R. Then $x_i$ are basis of $N/mN$ as R/m Vector space , so as to show rank of R-free module is unique . For that I want to prove that none of the $x_i$ belongs to **m**N

Comment: @shivering soldier  you can assume that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is trivial.

Suppose it is linearly independent, then

$$x_n=\alpha_1 x_1+\dots+\alpha_nmx_n$$

Which shows $\alpha_nm-1=0$. So $m$ is unit. A contradiction to maximality of **m**

Comment: $x_1,..., mx_n$ are elements of $N$ which spans $N$ as R module. I use the same notation in my question

Comment: And where did you use the hypothesis that N is free?

Comment: I haven't use it here. It's not necessary but at first I thought that hypothesis would be necessary.  ( I thought if  $x_1,...mx_n$ for basis then $N$ is free but now since the last element is $mx_n$ this module is not isomorphic to $R^n$.  A contradiction for module being free)